# SQL join for two tables, with same column names on Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

There are already a few questions with the same problems, I have all they looked, but still no solution found.
I would like to merge and count from two tables, the column with the same name (device_id).

column names: events and gender_age_train

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection

db_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///devices-train.db')

join_devices = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT device_id, count(device_id), gender_age_train.device_id, count(gender_age_train.device_id) FROM events JOIN gender_age_train on events.device_id = gender_age_train.device_id GROUP BY device_id', db_engine)

print join_devices
```

the python output is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) ambiguous column name: device_id [SQL: 'SELECT device_id, count(device_id), gender_age_train.device_id, count(gender_age_train.device_id) FROM events JOIN gender_age_train on events.device_id = gender_age_train.device_id GROUP BY device_id']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the `device_id` column since, as you noted, it appears in both tables. It's worth noting that it's a tad pointless to select both `events.device_id` and `gender_age_train.device_id` as they are equal (according to the `join` condition). Selecting one of them should suffice:

```
SELECT   e.device_id, COUNT(*)
FROM     events e
JOIN     gender_age_train g on e.device_id = g.device_id 
GROUP BY e.device_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Now there are no errors, but the output bring me to think about the data. 60.865 devices are available in "events", 74.645 devices are available in "gender_age_train". But how can now come out with the join 23.309?

Comment: @harun . . . Because this query only counts devices that match between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

When the columns used for joining have the same name, you can use the [USING clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause). This not only saves typing, but also removes the duplicate column from the join output so that you can more easily refer to it:

```sql
SELECT   device_id, COUNT(*)
FROM     events
JOIN     gender_age_train USING (device_id)
GROUP BY device_id;
```